# Eclipse birt can't establish connection to derby database

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, derby, birt

I'm creating a jdbc dataSource using derby db. I noted that `birt` actually comes with the derby embedded driver so I'm using it. After completing database/user/password, I'm getting an exception.

After that I tried adding my own derby.jar file. It works at first attempt but after restarting `birt`, it doesn't so I have to remove and add again the jar to the datasource :(. Any cues about solving this?

**The exception with birt's default derby embedded driver**

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Failed to start database 'C:/Users/david/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Sabino/database/engine', see the next exception for details..
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:339)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:210)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.tryCreateConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:827)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.testConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:748)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:147)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:175)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper.testConnection(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:961)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper.access$11(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:929)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper$8.widgetSelected(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:852)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.open(BaseDialog.java:111)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.providers.EditableDataSourceNodeProvider.performEdit(EditableDataSourceNodeProvider.java:73)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.DefaultNodeProvider.performRequest(DefaultNodeProvider.java:472)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.actions.EditAction.doAction(EditAction.java:85)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.actions.AbstractElementAction.run(AbstractElementAction.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.RenameListener.doubleClick(RenameListener.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:831)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:828)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1472)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1237)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: When it says "see the next exception for details", this is what it means: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: A simple thing to check, since you're alternating between two different copies of the Derby jars: make sure all the copies are the same version, otherwise you can have problems where older Derby software can't access a database created by newer Derby software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Bryan Pendleton,

After reviewing derby.log I found that eclipse birt comes with derby 10.5 and I was working with derby 10.11. So the old driver can't connect a database created with the new driver.

I replaced the eclipse birt's derby driver with my own and now it's working fine.